# Why does JavaFX ImageView snapshot shows a wrong size?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a large image that I'm loading from a file. I need to put it on two ImageView's (ivInput,ivLayer1) and resize it to 32x32. ivInput is resizing to 32x32 succesfully, but when I take its snapshot it has a wrong size (32x25).

```
 Image imgLetterBox = loadFromFile("m1.png");
 ivInput.setImage(imgLetterBox);
 ivInput.setFitWidth(32);
 ivInput.setFitHeight(32);
 System.out.println("ImgInput:" + ivInput.getFitWidth() + ", " + ivInput.getFitHeight());//32x32, it's ok
 Image imgLayer1 = ivInput.snapshot(null,null);
 System.out.println("ImgLayer1:" + imgLayer1.getWidth() + ", " + imgLayer1.getHeight());//32x25. why?
```

Comment: Is your `ImageView` (`ivInput`) a child of some container which resizes the `imageView`?

Comment: Yes, `HBox` container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in PreserveRatio property, it was on true value. I changed it on disable value and it is working well now.